# Salvar array php no banco de dados mysql

Tags: php, mysql, array

Estou precisando salvar um array em um campo na tabela do banco de dados e gostaria de saber qual melhor forma de fazer isso, se usando o [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.serialize.php) e [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unserialize.php) ou [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php)  e [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php).
Sei que tem outras alternativas também para isso, como por exemplo, podendo usar o `explode` e `implode` ou até melhor criar uma outra tabela auxiliar para isso, mas essa opção de criar a tabela auxiliar já foi descartada e a outra acho que seria a pior opção.

Comment: vc vai precisar fazer pesquisa nesse campo?

Comment: nesse campo em especifico ira ter apenas numeros, que por sinal, em cada um nao deve passar de 3 itens e sim, pode ser que eu tenha que pesquisar nesse campo e para isso pensei em usar um like e é certo que nao irei precisar fazer nenhum join.

Comment: Existe uma conceito básico de não trabalhar o que não precisas, e consoante as funções que descreveste, deves usar a mais conveniente para o tipo de dados com que queres trabalhar. Já que colocaste as _tags_ _php, mysql_, seria bom ver uma parte do código em questão, para que possamos entender melhor do que se trata.

Answer (score 2):

Eu normalmente costumo usar o serialize. 
Mas atenção, o array vai ser gigante? Se for gigante aconselho a mudar o tamanho maximo da variavel no SQL para longtext em vez de text/varchar etc... Senão corres o risco de pensares que estás a guardar tudo bem e na final estás com um array corrompido na tabela.

Mas pronto, voltando a questão de guardar um array numa tabela.
Eu uso bastantes vezes principalmente quando quero guardar logs de importações de Excel.

Normalmente faço serialize para guardar e unserialize quando preciso de trabalhar o array novamente.
Nunca tive problemas.

A tabela poderá eventualmente ficar grande dependendo do tipo do array claro.

Não conselho explode ou implode visto que com um array serialized tu tens sempre o array comprimido e isso é garantido. Um unserialize e tens o array novamente como de inicio :)

Espero ter ajudado.

Cumprimentos